# error "cannot display this video mode"

Tags: video, display, settings

The installation seemed to go well, but after the restart, I only get a black screen with a white text message that says "cannot display this video mode".  How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! please provide more information. What distribution are you currently using?

Answer (score 2):

I waited for 10 - 20 seconds on that "cannot display this video mode" screen and then Ubuntu 12.04 desktop came up. this is because the default OS will be selected for booting after timeout if we do not disturb anything. (hands away from keyboard)

After logging in, I edited `/etc/default/grub`

In terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Uncomment the line (removed the `#`) for `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and save the file.

Again in terminal, I ran `update-grub`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

rebooted then and I could see grub!